# Why azure web service failed to start with react scripts?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am deploying node app to `Azure Web Service`. This is a `mean` stack app. It works fine if I only includes `node` related scripts to the `scripts` section in `package.json`.

My working `package.json` is

```
{
  "name": "mytask2do-chatting",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://testing.com/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.7.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "app-root-path": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "create-react-app": "^3.0.1",
    "custom-error": "^0.2.1",
    "decode-uri-component": "^0.2.0",
    "detect-browser": "^4.2.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "enum": "^2.5.0",
    "file-type": "^10.9.0",
    "get-urls": "^9.0.0",
    "html-metadata": "^1.7.0",
    "html-to-text": "^4.0.0",
    "image-exists": "^1.1.0",
    "is-image": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "log-to-file": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "query-string": "^6.4.2",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-awesome-modal": "^2.0.5",
    "react-browser-detection": "^1.2.1",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.3.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.1",
    "react-desktop-notification": "^1.0.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-file-viewer": "^0.5.0",
    "react-global": "^0.1.8",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.2",
    "react-grid-system": "^4.4.3",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.5",
    "react-mixin": "^2.0.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-modal-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
    "react-ms-login": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-scripts": "^2.0.1",
    "react-page-visibility": "^4.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-config": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remote-file-size": "^3.0.5",
    "simple-react-modal": "^0.5.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "tedious-connection-pool": "^1.0.5",
    "universal-cookie": "^3.0.7",
    "url-metadata": "^2.4.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "winston": "^3.1.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^3.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server/index.js",
    "server": "node src/server/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run react\" \"npm run server\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

But if I include two `scripts` in the `package.json` scripts section

```
"react": "set PORT=3001 & react-scripts start",
"build": "SET NODE_ENV=production &&  react-scripts build"
```

I am getting error like `node_modules` not found and `app is failed to startup`.

Updated `package.json` becomes (This `package.json` shows error),

```
{
  "name": "mytask2do-chatting",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://testing.com/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.7.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "app-root-path": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "create-react-app": "^3.0.1",
    "custom-error": "^0.2.1",
    "decode-uri-component": "^0.2.0",
    "detect-browser": "^4.2.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "enum": "^2.5.0",
    "file-type": "^10.9.0",
    "get-urls": "^9.0.0",
    "html-metadata": "^1.7.0",
    "html-to-text": "^4.0.0",
    "image-exists": "^1.1.0",
    "is-image": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "log-to-file": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "query-string": "^6.4.2",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-awesome-modal": "^2.0.5",
    "react-browser-detection": "^1.2.1",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.3.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.1",
    "react-desktop-notification": "^1.0.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-file-viewer": "^0.5.0",
    "react-global": "^0.1.8",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.2",
    "react-grid-system": "^4.4.3",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.5",
    "react-mixin": "^2.0.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-modal-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
    "react-ms-login": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-scripts": "^2.0.1",
    "react-page-visibility": "^4.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-config": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remote-file-size": "^3.0.5",
    "simple-react-modal": "^0.5.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "tedious-connection-pool": "^1.0.5",
    "universal-cookie": "^3.0.7",
    "url-metadata": "^2.4.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "winston": "^3.1.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^3.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server/index.js",
    "server": "node src/server/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run react\" \"npm run server\"",
    "react": "set PORT=3001 & react-scripts start",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production &&  react-scripts build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

In `log streams` It says `node_modules` not found. Also, the `failed to startup`.

In `Azure web service` the configurations are

-> Stack Node

-> Node 12Lts

-> Startup Command `NODE_ENV=production npm start`

Can anyone give me any idea why I am getting the error while adding `react` related script?

NB: `react` related scripts are only required in the `development` not in `production`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to deploy your React app it as a App Services PHP image until they have fixed an image for js apps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/21005/view.html